# How to extract string following a pattern with grep, regex or perl

Tags: regex, perl, sed, html-parsing, text-extraction

I have a file that looks something like this:

```xml
    <table name="content_analyzer" primary-key="id">
      <type="global" />
    </table>
    <table name="content_analyzer2" primary-key="id">
      <type="global" />
    </table>
    <table name="content_analyzer_items" primary-key="id">
      <type="global" />
    </table>
```

I need to extract anything within the quotes that follow `name=`, i.e., `content_analyzer`, `content_analyzer2` and `content_analyzer_items`.

I am doing this on a Linux box, so a solution using sed, perl, grep or bash is fine.

Comment: no need to be shy, welcome here!

Comment: I feel that it would be wrong not to link to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Thanks everyone for the useful comments. I apologize for the XML not being properly formatted. I deleted some tags for simplification.

Answer (score 222, accepted):

Since you need to match content without including it in the result (must
match `name="`  but it's not  part of the  desired result) some  form of
zero-width matching  or group  capturing is required.  This can  be done
easily with the following tools:

#### Perl

With Perl you  could use the `n`  option to loop line by  line and print
the content of a capturing group if it matches:

```
perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if /name="(.*?)"/' filename
```

#### GNU grep

If you have an improved version of  grep, such as GNU grep, you may have
the  `-P` option  available. This  option will  enable Perl-like  regex,
allowing you to use `\K` which  is a shorthand lookbehind. It will reset
the match position, so anything before it is zero-width.

```
grep -Po 'name="\K.*?(?=")' filename
```

The `o`  option makes grep print  only the matched text,  instead of the
whole line.

#### Vim - Text Editor

Another way  is to  use a  text editor  directly. With  Vim, one  of the
various  ways of  accomplishing this  would be  to delete  lines without
`name=` and then extract the content from the resulting lines:

```
:v/.*name="\v([^"]+).*/d|%s//\1
```

---

#### Standard grep

If you  don't have  access to  these tools,  for some  reason, something
similar could be achieved with  standard grep. However, without the look
around it will require some cleanup later:

```
grep -o 'name="[^"]*"' filename
```

---

#### A note about saving results

In all of the commands above the  results will be sent to `stdout`. It's
important to remember  that you can always  save them by piping  it to a
file by appending:

```
> result
```

to the end of the command.

Comment: Lookarounds (in GNU `grep`): `grep -Po '.*name="\K.*?(?=".*)'`

Comment: @Dennis Williamson, great. I updated the answer accordingly, but left both `.*` aside, I hope you don't get angry with me. I'd like to ask, do you see any benefits from un-greedy match over "anything except `"`"? Don't take this as a fight, I'm just curious and I'm not a regex expert. Also, the `\K` tip, really nice. Thanks Dennis.

Comment: Why would I be angry? Without the `.*`, you can do `grep -Po '(?<=name=").*?(?=")'`. The `\K` can be used for shorthand, but it's really only needed if the match to its left is variable length. In cases like this, the reason for using lookarounds is fairly obvious. Ungreedy operations look a little neater (`[^"]*` versus `.*?` and you don't have to repeat the anchor character. I don't know about speed. That depends a lot on the context, I think. I hope that's helpful.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson: certainly sir, a lot of helpful information here. I think the reason I kept the `\K` (after researching on it) and removed the `.*` was the same: make it look pretty (simpler). And I've never thought in using `.*?` instead of the "traditional way" I learned from somewhere. But un-greedy here really makes sense. Thanks Dennis, best wishes.

Comment: +1 for describing the command.  Would appreciate it if you could update your answer to explain the "[...]" part of the regex.

Comment: @lreeder Thank you. That is a character class, when it begins with `^` that means it matches anything except its contents. So `[^"]` means every character that's not a quote. I didn't use it in the latter answer in favor of the unready version, `.*?`. The previous was greedy, so I used that class to match everything not a quote with the intention of stopping on the first quote, which is the same as matching anything "ungreedly" up to a quote. Hope this helps understanding it, let me know if I can clarify better some part.

Comment: The -P flag does not seem to be supported on OS X: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
 [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
 [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
 [--null] [pattern] [file ...]

Comment: @PerQuestedAronsson its is cited in the manual as extension. Not sure how documented it is, but well, I'm on OS X as well and works here.

Comment: @sidyll: I found this article: "Perl Regex Removed From Grep in Mountain Lion" (http://www.dirtdon.com/?p=1452 ). I'm on Yosemite myself, but the article seems to be valid for that as well.

Comment: On OS X, simply install `grep` via homebrew and use that instead of the default one. It should work.

Comment: `grep -Po 'look-ahead \K capture'` made my day. Slick.

Answer (score 6):

The regular expression would be:

```
.+name="([^"]+)"
```

Then the grouping would be in the \1

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Perl, download a module to parse the XML: [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-Simple-2.18/lib/XML/Simple.pm), [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig-3.37/Twig_pm.slow), or [XML::LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/~pajas/XML-LibXML-1.70/LibXML.pod).  Don't re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Note that example OP gave is not well-formed (`<type="global"` for instance), so most of XML parsers just complain and die.

Answer (score 5):

An HTML parser should be used for this purpose rather than regular expressions. A Perl program that makes use of [`HTML::TreeBuilder`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilder):

### Program

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::TreeBuilder;

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_file( \*DATA );
my @elements = $tree->look_down(
    sub { defined $_[0]->attr('name') }
);

for (@elements) {
    print $_->attr('name'), "\n";
}

__DATA__
<table name="content_analyzer" primary-key="id">
  <type="global" />
</table>
<table name="content_analyzer2" primary-key="id">
  <type="global" />
</table>
<table name="content_analyzer_items" primary-key="id">
  <type="global" />
</table>
```

### Output

```
content_analyzer
content_analyzer2
content_analyzer_items
```

Answer (score 2):

this could do it:

```
perl -ne 'if(m/name="(.*?)"/){ print $1 . "\n"; }'
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using HTML tidy & xmlstarlet:

```
htmlstr='
<table name="content_analyzer" primary-key="id">
<type="global" />
</table>
<table name="content_analyzer2" primary-key="id">
<type="global" />
</table>
<table name="content_analyzer_items" primary-key="id">
<type="global" />
</table>
'

echo "$htmlstr" | tidy -q -c -wrap 0 -numeric -asxml -utf8 --merge-divs yes --merge-spans yes 2>/dev/null |
sed '/type="global"/d' |
xmlstarlet sel -N x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" -T -t -m "//x:table" -v '@name' -n
```

Answer (score 1):

Oops, the sed command has to precede the tidy command of course:

```
echo "$htmlstr" | 
sed '/type="global"/d' |
tidy -q -c -wrap 0 -numeric -asxml -utf8 --merge-divs yes --merge-spans yes 2>/dev/null |
xmlstarlet sel -N x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" -T -t -m "//x:table" -v '@name' -n
```

Answer (score 0):

If the structure of your xml (or text in general) is fixed, the easiest way is using `cut`. For your specific case:

```
echo '<table name="content_analyzer" primary-key="id">
  <type="global" />
</table>
<table name="content_analyzer2" primary-key="id">
  <type="global" />
</table>
<table name="content_analyzer_items" primary-key="id">
  <type="global" />
</table>' | grep name= | cut -f2 -d '"'
```