# Get JSON value from URL in BASH

Tags: json, bash, parsing, url

I need to get the "snapshot" value at the top of the file from this url: https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/versions/versions.json

So I should get a variable that contains "14w08a" when I run the command to parse the json.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

best thing to do is use a tool with a JSON parser. For example:

```
value=$(
  curl -s "$url" |
  ruby -rjson -e 'data = JSON.parse(STDIN.read); puts data["latest"]["snapshot"]'
)
```

Answer (score 7):

This will do the trick

```
$ curl -s "$url" | grep -Pom 1 '"snapshot": "\K[^"]*'
14w08a
```

Comment: +1 for this pragmatic approach (in general, @glennjackman's approach offers more flexibility); version for platforms where `-P` is not supported (e.g, OSX): `curl -s "$url" | egrep -m 1 '"snapshot"' | awk -F '"' '{ print $4 }'`

Comment: `-Pom` has three options: [`-P` is for `--perl-regexp`, and `-o` is for `--only-matching`, and `-m` is for `--max-count`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html). And p[`\K` is `perl-regexp` flavor for a variable-length lookbehind](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33573989/1175496), "`\K` tells the engine to pretend that the match attempt started at this position."; another [example shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5081519/1175496)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ curl -s "$url" | jq -r .snapshot
14w08a
```