# Match a string in a file and print entire value using sed or awk

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk, sed

I am trying to extract the value associated with string, but need an optimal way.

```
name=sandeep login_name=sn003 version=3.0 rel_no=456....
```

The above text is stored in a file.
I am trying to search for a part of string and then print the entire value.

Say I need to search using `login` and output should be

```
login_name=sn003
```

I have tried the command

```
cat filename | awk -F" " '{print $2}'
```

If `login_name` is not the second field this will not print though.
How can i search for a string in any position and then print the result ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to extract string following a pattern with GREP, REGEX or PERL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080988/how-to-extract-string-following-a-pattern-with-grep-regex-or-perl)

Answer (score 2):

You could use grep,

```
$ echo 'name=sandeep login_name=sn003 version=3.0 rel_no=456.....' | grep -o '[^ ]*login[^ ]*'
login_name=sn003
```

`[^ ]*` matches any character but not of a space, zero or more times.

OR

Through sed,

```
$ echo 'name=sandeep login_name=sn003 version=3.0 rel_no=456.....' | sed 's/.*\([^ ]*login[^ ]*\).*/\1/'
login_name=sn003
```

OR

Through awk,

```
$ echo 'name=sandeep login_name=sn003 version=3.0 rel_no=456.....' | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/login/){print $i}}}'
login_name=sn003
```

Answer (score 0):

use perl:

```
perl -lne 'print $1 if(/(login[\S]+\s).*/)'
```