# How do I only copy a certain part using grep command

Tags: linux, bash, jenkins, groovy, grep

I am trying to run this command

```
svn info svn://xyz-repo/svn/xyzclientjs/branches/features/CRE-406 | grep 'Relative URL'
```

which gives me this

```
Relative URL: ^/branches/features/CRE-406
```

I want to copy everything after the "^/"

so I only get this as output

```
branches/features/CRE-406
```

I tried using grep -v "^/" 'Relative URL' but it didnt worked. Please any suggestions are highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have GNU grep, you can use Perl syntax regex:

```
svn info svn://xyz-repo/svn/xyzclientjs/branches/features/CRE-406 | grep -Po 'Relative URL: \^/\K.*'
```

See also related answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5081519/72178.